# P4Python cannot use progress class

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I don’t know why this will raise AttributeError, but in document it seems right https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4python/Content/P4Python/python.p4_progress.html

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception, Progress
from tqdm import tqdm


class P4ProgressHandler(Progress):
    TYPES = ["Unknown", "Submit", "Sync", "Clone"]
    pbar = None

    def init(self, type):
        super().init(type)
        if self.pbar is not None:
            self.pbar.close()
        self.pbar = tqdm(desc="P4 Progress: {}".format(self.TYPES[type]))

    def setDescription(self, description, units):
        super().setDescription(description, units)

    def setTotal(self, total):
        super().setTotal(total)
        self.pbar.total = total

    def update(self, position):
        super().update(position)
        if self.pbar is not None:
            self.pbar.update(position)

    def done(self, fail):
        super().done(fail)
        if self.pbar is not None:
            self.pbar.close()
p4 = P4()
p4.using_progress(P4ProgressHandler())
```

Python Version: 3.10.0

P4Python Version: P4PYTHON/"NTX64"/"2022.1"/"2299330" ("2022.1/2285021" API) ("2022"/"06"/"14").

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ForgeCI\ForgeCI\Utils\P4Methods.py", line 37, in <module>
    p4.using_progress(P4ProgressHandler())
  File "E:\ForgeCI\venv\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 517, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: using_progress
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message you are getting. That message actually provides a lot of information useful in diagnosing a problem; especially for AttributeErrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc for the `P4` class, there is no `using_progress` method:

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4python/Content/P4Python/python.p4.html#Instance_Methods_..39

Between that and the `AttributeError` I think it's safe to assume that the mention of `P4.using_progress` in the doc for the `Progress` class is an error in the doc.  Since `progress` is a property of `P4`, you should be able to replace:

```
p4.using_progress(P4ProgressHandler())
```

with:

```
p4.progress = P4ProgressHandler()
```

Comment: That does not raise Errors, but also does not work,  `P4` instance will not call any method in progress class during process.

Comment: There are only specific commands that will call the progress handler, and only under specific circumstances.  What command are you running?

Comment: I don't know why, but suddenly it works, thanks.